# Retrieving data from REST API

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, arrows

I am trying to implement my first project in Laravel that will contain APIs, more specifically the Sportmonks API. What is the best way to get the data and display it in my view?

I have managed to display some of the data, but I do not know the correct way to display the data from the "standings", as well as from the tables that it has in it (overall, home, away, total)

API returns

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 77447501,
        "name": "1st Phase",
        "league_id": 501,
        "season_id": 17141,
        "round_id": 195000,
        "round_name": 33,
        "type": "Group Stage",
        "stage_id": 77447501,
        "stage_name": "1st Phase",
        "resource": "stage",
        "standings": {
            "data": [{
                "position": 1,
                "team_id": 62,
                "team_name": "Rangers",
                "round_id": 195000,
                "round_name": 33,
                "group_id": null,
                "group_name": null,
                "overall": {
                    "games_played": 33,
                    "won": 28,
                    "draw": 5,
                    "lost": 0,
                    "goals_scored": 78,
                    "goals_against": 10,
                    "points": 89
                },
                "home": {
                    "games_played": 16,
                    "won": 16,
                    "draw": 0,
                    "lost": 0,
                    "goals_scored": 47,
                    "goals_against": 2,
                    "points": 48
                },
                "away": {
                    "games_played": 17,
                    "won": 12,
                    "draw": 5,
                    "lost": 0,
                    "goals_scored": 31,
                    "goals_against": 8,
                    "points": 41
                },
                "total": {
                    "goal_difference": "68",
                    "points": 89
                },
                "result": "Championship Round",
                "points": 89,
                "recent_form": "WWWWD",
                "status": null
            }],....
        }
    }]
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    $response = Http::get('apiurl');
    $response->json();
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    $matches = $result['data'];
    return view('/api', compact('matches'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning json you can return object

```
$response = Http::get('apiurl');
$result=$response->object();
$matches=$result->data;

return view('/api', compact('matches'));
```

then in your view

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
 
  @foeach($match->standings->data as $standing)

   {{$standing->team_name??null}}

  @endforeach
 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it your way, but it returns ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$team_name (View: ...-app/resources/views/api.blade.php)

Comment: @fsociety.updated answer.so you can test it in controller

Comment: @fsociety.got it try {{$standing->team_name??null}} this becuase few doesnt have property team_name

Comment: Ohh ! It works now. Thanks for your help, I spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong. Now,  one last question , how can I also get data from standings->overall (ex. games_played).

Comment: {{$standing->overall->games_played??null}}